# When is using transaction necessary in a web app?

Tags: sql, database, web, transactions

I am wondering, if a web request handler needs to perform multiple update queries that needs to be an atomic group, like this in a Django app:

```
modelA.fieldX = True
modelA.save()   # produce a update query on modelA table
modelB.fieldY = modelB.fieldY + 1
modelB.save()   # produce a update query on modelB table
```

And there is no logical branch taken or exceptions thrown between the queries, do I still need to wrap the queries in a transaction?

And what is the downside of wrapping them in a transaction? How does it affect the performance of other queries on the relevant tables?

EDIT:
Currently, I only use transactions for money-related queries, just to be safe.

Comment: Are you getting errors when you don't use transactions?

Comment: Ask yourself two questions: 1) will your data be consistent, if exception occurs between updating tables A and B (B will not be updated) and 2) will your data be consistent, if another client performs similar batch of updates on same records between your updates A and B? If not (either 1 or 2), then you need transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, transactions are necessary for data consistency. As an example, when you transfer money from account A to account B you should update the amounts in accounts A and B in the transaction to avoid situations when you decrease the amount of account A but the amount of account B is not increased due to an exception or other reason.

Long transactions are bad for relational databases because it increases locking of DB resources and increases overhead costs for it

I suggest using as short transactions as it possible to be sure about the consistency of your data.